# org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException when I run the selenium code by using a loop

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, qa-developer, coded-ui-tests

I'm getting an Exception as below ,when i run the selenium code by using a loop. It executes some steps and then display the message.

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: *[name='user']

My code is:

```
package login;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class login {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Web Driver configuration
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "E:\\Software\\geckodriver-v0.11.1-win64\\geckodriver.exe");

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver  ();
        String baseURL = "http://10.10.80.11/";
        driver.get(baseURL);


        // Login_logout Process     
        for (int i=1;i<=100;i++){
            WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("user"));                            

            // Enter user id
            element.sendKeys("abc");

            WebElement element1 = driver.findElement(By.name("password")); 

            // Enter user id
            element1.sendKeys("abc");
            driver.findElement(By.id("button-1013-btnEl")).click(); //Submit button
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.findElement(By.id("button-1021-btnEl")).click(); 
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            String expectedURL = "http://10.10.80.11/";
            String actualURL;
            actualURL = driver.getCurrentUrl();

            //compare the actual URL of the page with the expected one and print
            if (actualURL.contentEquals(expectedURL)){
                System.out.println(+i);
            } 
            else {   
                System.out.println("Test Fail!");
            }
        }     
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems you skipped logout step before next login..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always use the explicit wait to let the webelement get loaded before performing any execution on it. A very common method used for the wait is as follows.

```
/* Initialize the WebDriverWait, with 30 seconds of wait time. */
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.name("user")));
```

Add this code before the line where you are getting the error.

Answer (score 1):

As per your code, you have already logged in that's why in second loop you can't find the `By.name("user")` element. Before ending the loop logout from the application and just after starting the loop re-load the base url using code  `driver.get(baseURL);`, so that you can come to the original page.

Answer (score 1):

```
import org.testng.Assert; // Importing Assert class from TestNG library

public class LoginPage
{
static WebDriver driver;

String  expectedurl = "http://example.com";


@BeforeClass
public static void setup() throws TestNGException, IOException, WriteException
{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\Selenium Jar\\chromedriver.exe");
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
}

@Test
public void data()
{

    driver.get("http://abc.com");

    WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.name("log"));
    username.clear();
    username.sendKeys("abc");

    WebElement pass = driver.findElement(By.name("pwd"));
    pass.clear();
    pass.sendKeys("pqr");

    WebElement submit = driver.findElement(By.name("Submit"));
    submit.click();

    String actual = driver.getCurrentUrl();

     Assert.assertEquals(actual,expectedurl);

}
```

Please Use Method for the different condition
.do not use loop for that and use annotation for the selenium  please read this link about annotation  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/testng/testng_basic_annotations.htm

Answer (score 1):

> I'm getting an Exception as below ,when i run the selenium code by
>   using a loop

- Agree with Keshav, **You missed to "logout" before next login attempt**.
- Add or implement logout step to be back on login screen

I have few suggestions:

**1. Avoid use of looping :**

- You must be aware of the execution in automation is little depend of previous line of code
- If any line not executed or failed to execute we have limitations to handle that [We can do it for some extend but not for all line 100%]
- It would be disadvantageous to use loop as if any thing get failed you will get false alarm

**2. Use more & more functions :**

- In your code you have written all your statements in one class
- To make things re-usable and minimized failures you can think of using small functions for actions
- Example: One function will accept username & password which will actual enter credentials and tap on login button. Second function for logout etc.

**3. Instead of loop, You can inject test data from xls and simple increase number of iterations**

- This will be most efficient way to implement without using loops